# Find the product $\sec x\cdot \csc x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

To be $\frac \pi2 < x < \pi $. If $$\tan^2 x+\cot^2 x +4\tan x + 4\cot x - 10=0,$$ find the product $\sec x\cdot \csc x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\tan t+\cot t=\sec t\csc t$$
$$\tan^2t+\cot ^2t=\sec^2 t\csc^2 t-2$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.